# R dplyr: how do I use left_join keeping only the first match?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two tables I want to join with a left_join.

```
table_joined <- left_join(table_x,table_y, by = type)
```

The problem is that *type* has multiple entries per type, such that there are multiple matches for table_y in table_x. This makes the resulting table_joined have more rows than table_x, accommodating for all the multiple matches. Is there any way I could keep only the first match, such that table_joined has the same number of rows as table_x?

I'm connecting to SQL tables on a server, so I'd love to keep using dplyr if possible.
Thanks!

Here are examples of my tables.

table_x

| x1 | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

table_y

| type | y1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA |
| A | AA |
| B | BB |
| B | BB |
| C | CC |

table_joined:

| x1 | type | y1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | AA |
| 1 | A | AA |
| 2 | B | BB |
| 2 | B | BB |
| 3 | C | CC |

desired output:

| x1 | type | y1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | AA |
| 2 | B | BB |
| 3 | C | CC |

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)` and desired output?

Comment: You can use `row_number` when referencing `table_y`. Something like `table_y %>% group_by(type) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)` . Then join using that.

Comment: I like your idea a lot @HarrisonJones! There is only one issue; I keep getting the sql server error "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY". I could not find an alternative around using row_number.

Comment: If multiple type rows in table_y are entirely identical as in the question then `left_join(table_x, distinct(table_y))`

Comment: OMG! It was that simple! Thanks @G.Grothendieck

Comment: Sounds like you're using the row_number function in SQL and not dplyr. What is the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing isn't how SQL joins work.

If you do want only one line per type, you need to make sure that each table used in the join only has one line per `type`.

You can use something like `distinct` to remove duplicates on table_y but it requires the rows completely match. If they don't, you need to figure out the logic about which row to keep on your own.

```
table_joined <- left_join(table_x, distinct(table_y), by = type)
```